# Merge two cells in a table using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, html-table

I have an XML file that I want to display in a table using xslt, I want to merge cells using colspan when two nodes have the same value, for example:

```
<Magasin>
    <bouteille>
        <marque>marque1</marque>       
    </bouteille>
    <bouteille>
        <marque>marque1</marque>
    </bouteille>
    <bouteille>
        <marque>marque2</marque>
    </bouteille>
</Magasin>
```

here is my xslt:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr><xsl:for-each select="document('Pub.xml')/Magasin/bouteille/marque">
<th><xsl:value-of select="."/></th>
</xsl:for-each></tr>
</thead>                            
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry i wasn't clear, i posted the real code.

Comment: This is a *grouping* question: can you use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I am using version 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0, you can do:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="document('Pub.xml')/Magasin/bouteille" group-adjacent="marque"> 
    <xsl:variable name="size" select="count(current-group())" />
    <th>
        <xsl:if test="$size gt 1">
            <xsl:attribute name="colspan" select="$size"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
    </th>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: Your solution really helped but what if one of the nodes is empty, it displays an error message: An empty sequence is not allowed as the @group-adjacent attribute of xsl:for-each-group.

Comment: What is the expected result in such case? Please edit your question and show us an example of input and expected output.

Comment: @Mina But that will rearrange the columns in case of marque1, marque2, marque1.

Comment: yes, but that doesn't matter since i just need to count their occurrences. the group-adjacent won't work if there there is a node missing, that's why we need to rearrange them, so there will be a sequence.

Comment: @Mina As I said earlier, I don't really understand your requirement. That's OK, as long as it works for you - I just wanted to make sure you are aware of the difference.